# How do you assign jQuery scripts to an article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, jquery

I'm working on adding a simple feature to a single Joomla article.
Editing the article itself is necessary in this case, I can't modify the template files (or add the JS to the entire site).

In the article editor (as per [the doc](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)), my article is as follows ...

```
    {source}
    <?php
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addStyleSheet('mycode/css/article_1.css');
        $doc->addScript('mycode/js/article_1.js');
    ?>
    {/source}

    <div id="article_1"></div>
```

When viewing the page, both CSS and JS are loaded, but `addScript()` is first-come-first-served, so my script (which contains jQuery) loads *before* jQuery. The console spits out:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

I tried changing the `addScript` line to ...

```
    $doc->addCustomTag('<script src="mycode/js/article_1.js" defer></script>');
```

... (note the `defer` tag) but that doesn't seem to do anything (the script isn't added). I saw somewhere that I could use ...

```
    $doc->addScript('mycode/js/article_1.js', 'text/javascript" defer="false');
```

... but the editor (both TinyMCE and CodeMirror) encodes the " above (to & quot;) which breaks that possibility.

I've also tried wrapping the `article_1.js` code in an event listener ...

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ ... }
```

... but that doesn't seem to help :\ I still get:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

How do you add a jQuery script from within an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround below, by calling jquery.framework from the article. It should override jquery.framework call that comes from your template so then jquery will be called before your script.

```
{source}
<?php
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addStyleSheet('mycode/css/article_1.css');
    $doc->addScript('mycode/js/article_1.js');
?>
{/source}

<div id="article_1"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't really *override* the call in the template. It just sets its place in line. The call to addScript puts that script in an array, and the array is processed first-in-first-out when the page is rendered. Since the article is processed before the template, anything added by the article gets rendered before the template adds do. By calling jquery.framework from the article like you did, you set it to render ahead of the article js. Meanwhile, when the template calls addScript later in the process, the system sees jQuery is already in the array, and skips duplicating it.

Comment: @Arlen - in the above code in the first line the JHtml class loader method is loading the whole jQuery framework in an article and in the above code nothing is checking whether the jQuery framework is already loaded or not (at least I do not see where it is checked). This can be later a source of conflicts if a module, plugin, component or the template itself is loading the same or other versions of jQuery libraries...

Comment: @Zollie I don't think you need to check whether jQuery framework is already loaded or not in this case, because as Arlen said, if the system sees jQuery is already in the array, it skips duplicating it.

Comment: @Zollie isn't it `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` is a common way to call jquery framework in joomla templates? Even in protostar this code is written literally like that, not preceded by checking block. 
I also usually use  `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` when I create a module that need jquery, and so far I have never see any jquery call duplication in my projects.

Comment: @webchun - yes, it is absolutely the standard way of loading jQuery framework in Joomla, no problem with that.

Comment: First, addScript isn't the right way to add jQuery; use jquery.framework. But since you want to use that, let's take a short codewalk. Document.php, line 511. The script URL is the index into the _scripts array. Give the same script URL 30 times, still only one entry. Ergo it will only render one. Test it yourself; put the same addScript line in your page 3 times, check and see how many times it shows up in the output. It gets more interesting when you want to add a version of the jQuery script that's not supported by the Joomla code, but you seem to want to use the one Joomla supplies.

Comment: Also, check the jquery.php file. When you callJHTML::_('jquery.framework') you end up there, line 38 for the start of the method. Line 52 there uses addScript to add the jquery framework, so if the framework has already been added, addScript won't add another copy from the same URL. (Different URLs are a different story. Joomla will let you do that; maybe there's a reason you want to load two jQuery's, so it will let you.)

Comment: @Arlen - Thanks for clearing that up! framework method indeed checks if the method is already loaded.

Comment: And this way the whole subject is cleared at least for later readers. :)

Comment: The only additional note I would make is that JHtml uses its’ own script method. More precisely in Joomla 3.x `HTMLHelper::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/custom/js/sample.js');` or `JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/custom/js/sample.js');`, since the api was changed. And in this method addScript() is called.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a jQuery conflict (more like noConflict issue). You should start and wrap your script for example like:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) { // if you want to use $
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Or redefine jQuery like:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function;       creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});
```

And with few other methods. These will release the conflict on the page.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

**Update:**

It is my fault or laziness that I have not given a short additional explanation about my answer.

First, the original question is two questions actually: 1. How to add scripts to articles? 2. What does the given error mean? And these are a bit misleading because it could get confusing answers.

On the question how to load scripts into articles the answer is relatively easy since there is addScript and some other obvious methods. And `addScript()` was already in the question so there was no problem with that. If you do not mistype your code then these will work.

The second question which is a bit more important in this question and it is what does this error mean?

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Now, this error is most of the time appears when jQuery framework is loaded in noConflict mode as usually is the case in Joomla. And if jQuery is loaded in noConflict mode then the `$` shortcut will not be available, thus the error appears, when you try to run your scripts with that shortcut. That is why I gave my answer as it is, as a good practice you should wrap your jQuery scripts as it is above. And that is also explaining why you should not load the whole jQuery framework again within an article (since most probably it is already loaded so that is not the problem and loading it into an article could cause other complications later).

Comment: That's not it :) What's happening is that the above script files are loading BEFORE jQuery when I add them from inside the article (it gives an `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error). Probably because the template is 5 years old, was probably not so great to begin with. Which is why I want to try solving this in the article.

Comment: I've just tried adding the scripts through a straight up `<script src="blah.js" defer>` in the code, and wrapping the scripts in the functions as you suggest (immediately after the DOMContentLoaded event listener) ... and it seems to have pushed me in the right direction ... Thank you for that, I'll mark your answer correct after a bit of testing.

Comment: I'm just a bit astonished that there's no `$doc->addScriptToEnd()` or `$doc->addStyleSheetToEnd()` function. Seriously, how are articles supposed to call unique, page-specific code??

Comment: @neokio - have you tried `$doc->addScriptDeclaration($content, $type = 'text/javascript')` or `$doc->addStyleSheet($url, $options = array(), $attribs = array())`(at joomla 4.0 this last one is deprecated). `addStyleDeclaration($content, $type = 'text/css')` should work though. Of course if and after the $doc object is defined and loaded on the particular page.

Comment: Thank you for the help! While the your solution requires every script to be within that wrapper, it definitely works. I'm marking @webchun's answer as correct, however, because it also allows me to include off-site (CDN served) jQuery scripts (which also works using the `<script ... defer>` method), and because it's such a clean one-line solution.

Comment: @neokio - no problem. My solution is handling totally different problem and question than webchuns’s solution since I do not consider a good practice if you load a complete jQuery library within an article (that will cause conflicts later on the pages). The jQuery library should be loaded globally on the site (maybe inside your default site template not within an article) and small custom scripts should be used/wrapped and then loaded as I gave it in my answer to avoid jQuery conflicts later. That would be the point of this subject. So loading the base jQuery library within an article, well...

Comment: I would never suggest that.